# SQLAdapter SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, adapter, procedure

How do I modify the statement so that it gets the lat and lon of every user except for the user that is currently logged on?

My code is as follows:

```
var getLocationStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("SELECT lat, lon FROM fieldservice.location WHERE userId = ?");

function getLocation(userId) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : getLocationStatement,
        parameters : [userId]
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you not just make you where statement `WHERE userId != ?`

Comment: @GarethD when i try to invoke getLocation procedure, i get this error: {
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight platform or project \/EMProject"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}